# Keeping jQuery generated form field after submit

Tags: jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, form-submit

Here is working jQuery which I'm using.

My Javascript in header:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form-order").hide();
    $('#list').change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'C' || $(this).val() == 'D') {
        $('#form-order').show();
      } else {
        $('#form-order').hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

And part of my body:

```
List:
<select name="list" id="list">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="D">D</option>
</select>

<div id="form-order">
Order: 
<select name="order" id="order">
<option value="class">class</option>
<option value="event">event</option>
</select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qJ539/1/

It works well before submit. If A or B is selected, `<div>` (second dropdown field) is not visible. And if selecting C or D, `<div>` is shown.

My problem is when submitting the form with selection C or D, it also hides the . So how I could keep the `<div>` visible in these cases?

I'm thinking that there should be solution which checks the status of my first dropdown field value and showing/hiding the `<div>`. My code will keep all selected values in dropdown fields after submit.

Little update:
The submit of form is done by `input_type=submit` element.

Comment: Since your page is reloading, you'll have to find a way to persist the fact that it is visible and show it on page load. What have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps the initial call to `.hide()` can be conditionally emitted to the page based on server-side logic?  The server-side code is aware of the context of the POST, and is what pre-sets the selected value in the response.

Comment: I have tried to get that div visible with this `if ($(this).val() == 'C') { $('#form-order').show(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form-order").hide();

    if ($('#list').val() == 'C' || $('#list').val() == 'D') {
        $('#form-order').show();
    } else {
        $('#form-order').hide();
    }

    $('#list').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'C' || $(this).val() == 'D') {
            $('#form-order').show();
        } else {
            $('#form-order').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I thought I already tested this kind of solution. I did something wrong, because now its working. Thx!

Comment: Glad I could help, would you care to accept my post as the correct answer?